# Checking if an index in a multidimensional array is an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, header

The code:

```
    $row['text'] = 'http://t.co/iBSiZZD4 and http://t.co/1rG3oNmc and http://t.co/HGFjwqHI and http://t.co/8UldEAVt';

    if(preg_match_all('|http:\/\/t.co\/.{1,8}|i',$row['text'],$matches)){
        foreach($matches[0] as $value){
            $headers = get_headers($value,1);
            if(is_array($headers['Location'])){
                $headers['Location'] = $headers['Location'][0];
            }
            $row['text'] = preg_replace('|http:\/\/t.co\/.{1,8}|i', '<a href="' . $headers['Location'] . '">' . $headers['Location'] . '</a>',$row['text']);
        }
    }
```

This is related to `get_headers()`.  Sometimes `get_headers($url,1)` returns an array with a location index key like so: `[Location]=>Array([0]=>url1 [1]=>url2)`.  I basically want to make `[Location]` equal to `[Location][0]` if `[Location][0]` exists.  However, the above code doesn't seem to accomplish that task.  I've also tried `array_key_exists()` and `isset()` but neither solved the problem.  Thoughts?

Comment: have you made sure `$headers['Location']` is an array?

Comment: `$headers['Location']` is not normally an array.  That's why I'm checking if it is an array so I can take alternative action.

Comment: this should work... Make sure that $headers is not read-only.

Comment: @cwscribner: What do you mean it doesn't work? What is the result you're getting?

Comment: Your code works fine for me, make sure your array looks like what you think it looks like. http://codepad.viper-7.com/DKjPM1

Comment: @Truth Added the full code.  It looks like what's happening is the first resolved link is being copied to all the links.  For example, `http://t.co/iBSiZZD4` is the first link in a paragraph containing 4 links.  The code resolves the first one and prints out the resolution 4 times like this: `http://yesilperi.org and http://yesilperi.org and http://yesilperi.org and http://yesilperi.org`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to replace on the fly. First get all the values, and then do the replace in one batch (using two arrays as the `$search` and `$replace` parameters).

```
<?php

    $replace = array();
    $row = array('text' => 'http://t.co/iBSiZZD4 and http://t.co/1rG3oNmc and http://t.co/HGFjwqHI and http://t.co/8UldEAVt');
    if (preg_match_all('|http:\/\/t.co\/.{1,8}|i', $row['text'], $search)) {
        foreach ($search[0] as $value) {
            $headers = get_headers($value, 1);
            if (is_array($headers['Location'])) {
                $headers['Location'] = $headers['Location'][0];
            }
            $replace[] = "<a href='{$headers["Location"]}'>{$headers["Location"]}</a>";
        }
        $row['text'] = str_replace($search[0], $replace, $row['text']);
        echo $row["text"];
    }
```

P.S. - Next time, please tell us the context of your problem, tell us you "are making a service that resolves shortened URLs", don't let me figure that out from your code alone.

Comment: On a side note, I think I may have to find an alternative to get_headers().  It keeps failing to open stream, maybe because of the amount of links I have.